# Php reload 10 times and echo a number

Tags: php, loops, refresh, reload

I have my code :

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){

    echo $i;
    header("Refresh:3");
    exit;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to reload page 10 times (I thought for loop could help) and echo each time a number. So it's basically like:

echo "0" then refresh and echo "1" then refresh and echo "2" and so on for 10 times.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're probably going to need to use $_SESSION. What's wrong in your loop is it resets every time the page reloads so it will never iterate to 10.

Comment: In my wildest dreams i see no scenario where you will need to do something like that. What are you trying to achieve? is it just practice or are you working on a live project? what is the end goal?

Comment: Honestly, I thought the same thing lol

Comment: I'm a student and a company gives us some tasks to do for a practise. It's hard to explain where am i using this. It's just a small part of my big code and this simple example helped me a lot :D.

Comment: as stated by @Mech , you need to find a way to persist your loop counter between each reload of the page. simply reloading a page will process the code from the start, it doesn't not persist anything. to persist a value, the simpler solution would be to use sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember where the counter is and that requires using the SESSION to get around the stateless nature of a web page

```
<?php
session_start();
if (! isset($_SESSION['cnt']) ) {
    $_SESSION['cnt'] = 0;
}

if ( $_SESSION['cnt'] < 10 ) {
    // show on page
    echo $_SESSION['cnt'];

    // increment count
    $_SESSION['cnt'] = $_SESSION['cnt'] + 1;

    header("Refresh:3");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! <3